# MYSQL query to get multiple statuses from statuses table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've two tables (MySQL) in my application related to tracking jobs.  The first table "jobs" contains one row for each job recorded in the system.  This is supported by a jobs progress table which keeps a track of the progress of a job with a new row added each time a job moves to a new state.  It is also possible that a job can be re-opened again and pushed back to a previous state.  Therefore the job_progress table could have multiple entries for the same job state but on different date/times.

I'd like to be able to get the current state of a job by getting the max date for a particular state via the jobs_progress table. I'd also like to be able to get for each job the date that it progressed through each state.  However I'm struggling to do this via SQL and would appreciate some help.  See the following SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b27f/4

Here's what I currently have:

```
SELECT j.*
     , jp.job_state
     , jp.effective_date
     , jp.user_id
  FROM jobs j
  LEFT
  JOIN jobs_progress jp
    ON jp.job_id = j.id;
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
| id | agency_id | entity_type | entity_id | job_title             | job_state | system_status | job_state     | effective_date      | user_id |
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
|  1 |       123 | PROPERTY    |        61 | set of keys to be cut | INVOICED  | ACTIVE        | NEW           | 2014-07-08 12:27:54 |     102 |
|  1 |       123 | PROPERTY    |        61 | set of keys to be cut | INVOICED  | ACTIVE        | APPROVED      | 2014-07-08 12:28:02 |     102 |
|  1 |       123 | PROPERTY    |        61 | set of keys to be cut | INVOICED  | ACTIVE        | ASSIGNED      | 2014-07-08 12:29:02 |     102 |
|  1 |       123 | PROPERTY    |        61 | set of keys to be cut | INVOICED  | ACTIVE        | WORK_COMPLETE | 2014-07-08 12:29:11 |     102 |
|  1 |       123 | PROPERTY    |        61 | set of keys to be cut | INVOICED  | ACTIVE        | INVOICED      | 2014-07-08 12:29:27 |     102 |
|  1 |       123 | PROPERTY    |        61 | set of keys to be cut | INVOICED  | ACTIVE        | ASSIGNED      | 2014-08-21 12:29:02 |     103 |
|  1 |       123 | PROPERTY    |        61 | set of keys to be cut | INVOICED  | ACTIVE        | WORK_COMPLETE | 2014-08-30 12:29:11 |     103 |
|  1 |       123 | PROPERTY    |        61 | set of keys to be cut | INVOICED  | ACTIVE        | INVOICED      | 2014-09-01 12:29:27 |     103 |
+----+-----------+-------------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Here's what I want:

```
+----+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | agency_id | job_title             | raised_date (NEW)   | approved_date (APPROVED) | assigned_date (ASSIGNED) | completed_date (WORK_COMPLETE) | invoiced_date (INVOICED)|
+----+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------+
|  1 |       123 | set of keys to be cut | 2014-07-08 12:27:54 | 2014-07-08 12:28:02      | 2014-08-21 12:29:02      | 2014-08-30 12:29:11            | 2014-09-01 12:29:27     | 
+----+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

And here's what I tried:

Comment: The SQL Fiddle is good, but you should edit your question and include what results you want (along with sample data).

Comment: which are the possible states?

Comment: is there any proper sequence in which only your state can be change?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  As per Gordon's comment, I perhaps should have made it a bit clearer the exact output that was required.  See updated question for output required. I've only included one row in this example but there will be 1000's of rows in the jobs table so performance is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show you the maximum date for each status, so should contain everything you want?

```
select 
  j.id,
  j.agency_id,
  j.entity_type,
  j.entity_id,
  j.job_title,
  j.system_status,
  jp.jobstate2 job_state,
  jp.effectivedate
from jobs j
inner join (select job_id,job_state jobstate2,max(effective_date) effectivedate
            from jobs_progress
            group by job_id,job_state) jp 
           on jp.job_id = j.id
order by effectivedate desc
```

EDIT: Following some more requirements being added

It looks liek you're after a PIVOTed output. As far as I know, there isn;t an easy way to do this in MySQL, but you could try this, which isn't pretty, but does produce the result you're after:

```
select 
  j.id,
  j.agency_id,
  j.entity_type,
  j.entity_id,
  j.job_title,
  j.system_status,
  j.job_state,
  jp_new.effectivedate raised_date,
  jp_approved.effectivedate approved_date,
  jp_assigned.effectivedate assigned_date,
  jp_complete.effectivedate complete_date,
  jp_invoiced.effectivedate invoice_date
from jobs j
inner join (select job_id,max(effective_date) effectivedate
            from jobs_progress
            where job_state = 'NEW'
            group by job_id,job_state) jp_new
           on jp_new.job_id = j.id
inner join (select job_id,max(effective_date) effectivedate
            from jobs_progress
            where job_state = 'APPROVED'
            group by job_id,job_state) jp_approved
           on jp_approved.job_id = j.id
inner join (select job_id,max(effective_date) effectivedate
            from jobs_progress
            where job_state = 'ASSIGNED'
            group by job_id,job_state) jp_assigned
           on jp_assigned.job_id = j.id
inner join (select job_id,max(effective_date) effectivedate
            from jobs_progress
            where job_state = 'WORK_COMPLETE'
            group by job_id,job_state) jp_complete
           on jp_complete.job_id = j.id
inner join (select job_id,max(effective_date) effectivedate
            from jobs_progress
            where job_state = 'INVOICED'
            group by job_id,job_state) jp_invoiced
           on jp_invoiced.job_id = j.id
```

EDIT: Following some more requirements being added

If you want to show jobs that haven't been through all of the stages, then use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`:

```
select 
  j.id,
  j.agency_id,
  j.entity_type,
  j.entity_id,
  j.job_title,
  j.system_status,
  j.job_state,
  jp_new.effectivedate raised_date,
  jp_approved.effectivedate approved_date,
  jp_assigned.effectivedate assigned_date,
  jp_complete.effectivedate complete_date,
  jp_invoiced.effectivedate invoice_date
from jobs j
left outer join (select job_id,max(effective_date) effectivedate
                 from jobs_progress
                 where job_state = 'NEW'
                 group by job_id,job_state) jp_new
                on jp_new.job_id = j.id
left outer join (select job_id,max(effective_date) effectivedate
                 from jobs_progress
                 where job_state = 'APPROVED'
                 group by job_id,job_state) jp_approved
                on jp_approved.job_id = j.id
left outer join (select job_id,max(effective_date) effectivedate
                 from jobs_progress
                 where job_state = 'ASSIGNED'
                 group by job_id,job_state) jp_assigned
                on jp_assigned.job_id = j.id
left outer join (select job_id,max(effective_date) effectivedate
                 from jobs_progress
                 where job_state = 'WORK_COMPLETE'
                 group by job_id,job_state) jp_complete
                on jp_complete.job_id = j.id
left outer join (select job_id,max(effective_date) effectivedate
                 from jobs_progress
                 where job_state = 'INVOICED'
                 group by job_id,job_state) jp_invoiced
                on jp_invoiced.job_id = j.id
```

Comment: Thanks @StevieG.  Nearly there.  This gives me these values for all jobs which are invoiced in the system, I need this to work for all statuses and if a job hasn't passed through any of these states it should set the date as NULL.

Comment: Thats simple enough too - just change the joins from `INNER` to `LEFT OUTER` - I'll update the answer again..

Comment: That's the one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the last date a row was invoiced.  If you want all the transition dates, how do you want that displayed?

```
select jobs.*, LastEntry.effective_date 
from jobs
INNER JOIN (SELECT job_id, MAX(effective_date) AS effective_date FROM jobs_progress WHERE job_state = 'INVOICED' GROUP BY job_id) AS LastEntry ON jobs.id = LastEntry.job_id
```

This will only show jobs that have been invoiced.  If you want to include jobs that have not been invoiced, then use a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the derived table instead of an inner join

Answer (score 0):

You can get job with latest effective_date without sub query. Joins will perform fast than sub queries when you are working with more data.

--> latest job

```
SELECT jb.id,
jb_pr1.job_state,
jb_pr1.effective_date
FROM 
jobs jb
INNER JOIN jobs_progress jb_pr1 on jb_pr1.job_id = jb.id
LEFT JOIN jobs_progress jb_pr2
ON (jb_pr1.job_id = jb_pr2.job_id AND jb_pr1.effective_date < jb_pr2.effective_date)
WHERE jb_pr2.effective_date IS NULL;
```

SQL Fiddle Link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b27f/41